# Resolve DNS mail validation synchronously or after time (JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, dns

I've added a domain validation of an email in a form using the Node [dns.resolveMx()](https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_dns_resolvemx_hostname_callback) method with a code similar to this

```js
const exampleDomain = 'gmail.com'
const isValid = false;
dns.resolveMx(exampleDomain, (error, addresses) => {
   if(!error) {
      isValid = true;
   }
}
```

This code works fine in my local environment, but crash in my other environments apparently because the callback function takes longer to resolve.

I've tried to use `Promise.race([])` but not sure how to define the "resolverFunction" to manage it

```js
const timeout = () => new Promise((res) => setTimeout(() => res(true), 3000))
const isValid = await Promise.race([resolverFunction, timeout]);
```

I would like force a sync process or resolve after a few seconds with a `true` value by default. Any idea?

Comment: Tip: Only using MX records to verify a domain is not good. If a domain accepts email and does not have an MX record, the A record for the domain is used for the email server. In other words, an MX record is not required. RFC 5321 makes an MX record optional.

Comment: I thought type 'A' was only for resolving IPv4, should I use for example `dns.resolveAny()` to make sure?

Comment: MX records eventually resolve to an A record also. Read the RFCs. You are making incorrect assumptions on how things actually work.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved my problem wrapping with a Promise in other function:

```js
const isValidEmail = await validateDns(domain);
// ...
const validateDns = async(domain) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    dns.resolveMx(domain, (error,addresses) => {
      if(error) {
        resolve(false);
      }
      resolve(true);
    })
  })
}
```

It works and solve the async problem with the callback in dns.resolve*() functions